# Android webview doesn't load correct css from html in night mode

Tags: android, webview, android-night-mode

I see style problems on the webview when I force night mode this way. 
Some texts and images have the wrong colors.

```java
    webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.loadUrl("myUrl")       

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        if (isInDarkMode()) {
            webView.settings.forceDark = WebSettings.FORCE_DARK_ON
        } else {
            webView.settings.forceDark = WebSettings.FORCE_DARK_OFF
        }
    }

    fun Activity.isInDarkMode(): Boolean {
        return (resources.configuration.uiMode and 
        Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES
    }
```

I did this because my webview doesn't switch by itself when the user changes the theme.

I'm using Android 10 and the latest Chrome version.

Comment: Post screenshot of difference between DARK LIGHT Mode.

Comment: i can't..sorry. I'll try to find a site where I have this problem. Doesn't anyone else have this kind of problem?

Comment: I feel like I don't have the problem when I force the darkmode at the beginning of the app.